# Does it require an action to drop 'Ball Bearings'?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

I was wondering if it's possible to use an attack action (ranged e.g.) and then when moving away (down a narrow corridor or the likes) dropping Ball bearings as a bonus action. Not sure if it counts as 'use object' action, as it seems plausible that you would be able to empty the bag behind you while running away.

Answer (score 13):

This is answered in the ball bearing's description on page 151 of the PHB (some emphasis added):

> **Ball Bearings. As an action,** you can spill these tiny metal balls from their pouch...

Comment: Ah.. Silly me, sometimes the asnwers are starring you right in the face :) Thanks mate.

Comment: Presumably you *could* drop a bag of ball bearings, if already held, as the once-per-turn free object interaction. However, even if a few of them might spill logically, it would simply not have the same mechanical effect, any more than dropping a hand axe in the same way would count as a ranged thrown weapon attack with it against someone below you.

Comment: As a DM, I'd say there's a difference between *dropping* and *scattering*.